# How to force php to free some memory without ending a session?

Tags: php

I have a php script that runs multiple times within one session.
It appears, that during these multiple runs my script reaches the [128MB memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
How can I forcefully free memory between different script runs, without losing some session variables, that are very small in size?
Thanks.
------------------------------
Update:
The problem appears to be elsewhere :-(

Comment: what script? can't debug the invisible. it is  unlikely it has anything to do with sessions.

Comment: That limit is per run of the script.  It doesn't accumulate across multiple runs.

Comment: Wyzard, are you sure? I use one session for all the runs.

Comment: php frees memory at the end of a script, but I'm not sure what a "run" is in this context

Comment: Thanks for the help, everybody. My mistake. I just checked the memory usage with memory_get_usage(), and it turned out to be OK, around 11 MB. The question is closed.

Comment: Delete the question then? Saves us opening and reading it? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using unset() manually after using a variable for the last time, within each script, to make sure PHP isn't holding onto variables when it shouldn't be. Other than that, without some knowledge of your attempted implementation, I doubt there will be any way to help more.